# Horizontally align two side-by-side input elements underneath two input elements

Tags: html, css

I have centered two input elements on top of each other inside a div and am attempting to place two submit elements under them.

Here is what I would like the outcome to be:

[image]

Instead, the two submit buttons aren't perfectly aligned with the input elements (I believe this is to do with `float: left;`:

```css
input[type="text"] {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 display: block;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 35%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: honest question... why two submit buttons?

Comment: @Jhecht Saves having to have two separate forums for login and register :)

Comment: If your login/register forms have the same set of fields (usually a register form asks for like email and username etc.) then why not just have your server-side code insert the record if one isn't found and then log them in? This means only 1 button!

Comment: @Jhecht What if they accidentally type their username wrong, which causes the system to create a new account?

Comment: What if they type in their username wrong and accidentally hit the wrong button? What submit button is defaulted if the user (like most of us) just hits enter after typing in a password?

Comment: you know out of sheer wonder I have figured out that if you hit enter it will default to the first input of type submit. make sure your register button is the second one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove float and set `text-align: center` on parent element.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: I like yours better than mine because it doesn't change the HTML like mine does.

Comment: Brilliant answer, cheers. Is it possible to eliminate the space between the two submit buttons?

Answer (score 1):

There might be another way to do it, but the easiest way I know of is to wrap those two elements in a parent element and simply apply the same margin/width

```css
input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.center-70 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<div class="center-70">
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this.

This is one of them:

```css
div.container {
  width: 70%;
}
input[type="text"] {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<input type="submit">
<input type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to solve this problem is using Grid Layout in your CSS codes.
you can learn about it on the below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)